# Jenkins running phing exectask. Exectask uses ssh agent forwarding. Permission denied. How to resolve?

Tags: java, ssh, nginx, jenkins, phing

## What went wrong

I have a ubuntu 12.10 server.

**I installed Jenkins and Nginx in the same server.**

The /var/virtual where Nginx is supposed to server files from has a permission settings of www-data:www-data

The user `jenkins` is running Jenkins the software.

[image]

This is my target written in phing build.xml

```
<target name="gitclone">
        <echo msg="gitclone ${environment.branch} branch code to ${environment} environment" />

        <exec command="ssh -A ${host-used} 'git clone -b ${repository-uri} ${environment.branch} ${environment.sitedir}${build.time}'"
         outputProperty="result" escape="false"/>
        <echo msg="${result}" />

        <echo msg="update all the submodules after gitclone" />
        <exec dir="${environment.sitedir}${build.time}" command="ssh -A ${host-used} 'git submodule update --init --recursive'" outputProperty="result" escape="false" />
        <echo msg="${result}" />

    </target>
```

This is my console output from jenkins:

```
[echo] gitclone master branch code to production environment
[echo] Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[echo] update all the submodules after gitclone
Execution of target "gitclone" failed for the following reason: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc-master/workspace/build.xml:116:48: '/var/virtual/abc.com/2013_01_11_07_45_35' is not a valid directory
```

## What I tried

I googled around and then I saw [this github article on ssh agent forwarding](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding).

This is what I tried.

I ssh into my server as jenkins.

Then I typed

```
ssh -T www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx
```

I was prompted for www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx password which I then gave. Note that xxx.xx.xxx.xx from now onwards refer to the ip address of the same server.

I successfully logged in as www-data, so I exited www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx. Now back in server as `jenkins` user.

Now I try

```
echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

I got nothing.

I went inside /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config and typed the following:

```
Host xxx.xx.xxx.xx
ForwardAgent yes
IdentityFile /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
StrictHostkeyChecking no
```

Build `Jenkins` job again. Fail.

Then I thought maybe I need to set the authorized_keys inside www-data ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file so that whenever we go from jenkins@xxx.xx.xxx.xx to www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx, I won't get prompted for password.

So as `jenkins`, I typed

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Then I typed

```
ssh -T www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx
```

I was prompted for www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx password which I then gave.

I successfully logged in as www-data **without getting prompted for password this time**, so I exited www-data@xxx.xx.xxx.xx. Now back in server as `jenkins` user.

Build `Jenkins` job again. Fail.

As `jenkins`, I typed

```
echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

Nothing was seen.

Tried

```
ssh-add -L
```

Got

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

Checked `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. No `ForwardAgent no` setting.

Build `Jenkins` job again. Fail.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question, but I like it and I hope you get an answer. You *might* add a [tag:java] tag since Jenkins is a Java product (?). [tag:ssh-agent] probably isn't doing anything for you, and most [tag:php] developers around here probably don't have a lot of build experience with this combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one I noticed that your git clone command may be written wrongly.

Check:

```
    <exec command="ssh -A ${host-used} 'git clone -b ${environment.branch} ${repository-uri} ${environment.sitedir}${build.time}'"
```

I swapped position of `${environment.branch}` and `${repository-uri}`.

Reference: [git-clone(1) Manual Page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html)

Comment: I figured out what's wrong. your suggestion was one of several errors I made. >.< Thank you Sam!!

Comment: No problem at all! what was the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use ant-jsch

I already use ant-jsch under jenkins.

ant-jsch are able to control ssh identify and so on